# Solidworks 2024 bend around circle sketch or cylinder?

Tags: solidworks

How do you in solidworks 2024 bend the part of body around circle sketch or cylinder

**Current result:**
[image: 1]
[image: 2]

**Expected result:**
[image: 3]

Comment: Sounds like you seek something called a "sweep" although you can probably use a revolve if that truly is a circle.  You can then delete the original pieces with surface modeling (deleting faces) since it appears to be an import